# What false === options[:url] means in case equality

Tags: ruby

Although it's a case equality statement, I can't figure out what exactly it means in the following sample code:

```
def initialize connection, options = {}
  @proxy = @uri = nil
  @connection = connection
  unless false === options[:url]
    url = options[:url] ? options[:url].dup : 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/'
    url << "/" unless url[-1] == ?/
    @uri = RSolr::Uri.create url
    if options[:proxy]
      proxy_url = options[:proxy].dup
      proxy_url << "/" unless proxy_url.nil? or proxy_url[-1] == ?/
      @proxy = RSolr::Uri.create proxy_url if proxy_url
    end
  end
  @options = options
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is wrong usage of `===` operator here. More idiomatic here would be using

```
if options[:url] != false
  # code
end
```

Because `false === options[:url]` will only works if `options[:url] == false`

Comment: The last sentence sounds confusing to me. `false ===` is a call of `#===` method on `FalseClass` instance. It is passing the call to superclass’ [`Object#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), that is just comparing `false` against RHO “effectively the same way as `#==`”.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, I meant that `false === smth` is equal to `false == smth`

Answer (score 1):

I belive that `#===` means exactly what `#==` means (in case of `false` and `true`, not generally) so this would be just poorly written code.

```
false === false # => true
false === nil   # => false
false === true  # => false
```